# serialize dictionary with Json.net and select query on entity

Tags: c#, .net, json, entity-framework, dictionary

I have code that looks like this...

```
var records = from part in this.DataWorkspace.AUTOData.TestParameterViews
    select new
      {Name = part.ParamName, Val = part.CurrentValue}     

File.WriteAllText(@"c:\params.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new{parameters = records }, Formatting.Indented));
```

The generated json file looks like this.....

```
{
 "parameters": [
 {
   "Name": "Var1",
   "Val": 6666.0
 },
 {
   "Name": "Var2",
   "Val": 1.0
 },
 {
   "Name": "Var3",
   "Val": 5500.0
 },
```

And so on...listing all the members within the entity.

PROBLEM:  I would like the json output to be in a dictionary format (shown below), but still query the entity.

```
"parameters": {
    "Var1": 6666.0,
    "Var2": 1.0,
    "Var3": 5500.0,
```

I have tried the following code but am hung up on syntax.  Specifically Intellisense is indicating an error on the `select` saying "Cannot implicitly convert type....An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)

```
Dictionary<string, float> records = from part in this.DataWorkspace.AUTOData.TestParameterViews
        select new Dictionary<string, float>
      {Name = part.ParamName, Val = part.CurrentValue}     

File.WriteAllText(@"c:\params.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new{parameters = records }, Formatting.Indented));
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Create the dictionary. Then loop thru TestParameterViews adding to the dictionary. Then serialize.

```
Dictionary<string, float> records = new Dictionary<string, float>();
this.DataWorkspace.AUTOData.TestParameterViews.ForEach(part => part.ParamName, part.CurrentValue);
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\params.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { parameters = records }, Formatting.Indented));
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble with the loop syntax. intellinsense is throwing an error on the `.ForEach` that you listed above.  I don't have a ForEach statement available to me within Intellisense autocomplete.  Is this EF syntax that i don't have a reference for?

Comment: Sorry for such a late response. It's in System.Collections.Generic. namespace as a method of List<>. Can you convert TestParameterViews to a  List

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx